# How to get min and max date time from time intervals in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have tried following way

```
SELECT MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time) FROM table WHERE date_time < date_sub(now(),interval 5 minute) AND date(date_time)='2019-09-10'
```

Table structure and except result
[image]

Comment: Do you want to get min and max of today records ?!

Comment: I think you mean your **expected** result.

Comment: I have mentioned except result on an image, that is if time interval greater than 5, a higher date is min value of the next result of the row, so I except multi-row of result set. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Convert the time to an integer, and divide this by 180 seconds to group by 3-minute intervals.

```
SELECT MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time) 
FROM table 
WHERE date_time < date_sub(now(),interval 5 minute) AND date(date_time)='2019-09-10'
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)/180)
```